# While read from file loop, run multiple threads

Tags: bash

I have constructed bash script which is not using threading. I would like to implement it with your help.

I am running on `Threadripper 3990X` meaning that I can run a lot of threads.

Right now my bash script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env python3

while true; do # Start
while read -r line; do  # 1
python3 script1.py -d $line --output file.txt # 2
done < domain && while read -r line; do  # 3
./script2 -d $line # 4
done < domain && while read -r line; do # 5
go run main.go -d $line -o file2.txt # 6
done < domain && mv *.txt /mnt/c/savehere && # 7
dos2unix savehere/*.txt && sort savehere/*.txt | uniq | tr -d '<>,' > results-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H_%p).txt && python3 discord-notify.py # 8
done # End
```

`domain` file contains `500-1500` list of domains which are then passed to `bash, python, golang` scripts line by line, after done, they output `.txt` files to `"root"` folder which is then moved to `/mnt/c/savehere` folder and merged together into one `.txt` file, after done notify me on discord and auto. start bash script again.

Speed is not really that much slow, however because I am running this strong CPU there is probably way to make this script run way faster and save a lot of time.

Comment: Your script is difficult to read, you should introduce some indentation. You loop over lines of the same file multiple times, why not only once? What exactly is it that you want to parallelize? Why is output both `file.txt` for both #2 and #6 ? You have an infinite loop around the whole thing. Why? Can you explain?

Comment: They dont really output file.txt, i modifed those scripts so they output [date].txt they just need those params.

I tought that I can run multiple threads so it goes through domain file faster, or will run script1.py multiple times at once while going through domain file - not sure which option is better. What I want is to speed up the process basically.

Like this it goes one by one. While it could do multiple at time.

Comment: ok, but if output is [date].txt and you run in parallel it might (and will) happen that [date] is the same and it will overwrite.

Comment: Dont worry about that, it wont happen because domain is pre-appended in the filename.
domain-[date + hours,minutes,seconds].txt

I am already running the script and its working how its supposed to. I just want to speed up the process by using more threads - if its possible.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118771/how-to-parallelize-a-shell-script-that-reads-lines-of-a-text-file-as-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper indentation really adds clarity. Don't forget to quote your
variables:

```bsh
while true; do
    while IFS= read -r line; do 
        python3 script1.py -d "$line" --output file.txt
    done < domain && 
    while IFS= read -r line; do 
        ./script2 -d "$line"
    done < domain && 
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        go run main.go -d "$line" -o file2.txt
    done < domain && 
    mv *.txt /mnt/c/savehere &&
    dos2unix savehere/*.txt && 
    sort savehere/*.txt | uniq | tr -d '<>,' > results-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H_%p).txt && 
    python3 discord-notify.py
done
```

`xargs` can act like a shell while-read loop, and will probably be a lot
faster:

```bsh
while true; do
    xargs -d '\n' -I LINE python3 script1.py -d LINE --output file.txt < domain &&
    xargs -d '\n' -I LINE ./script2 -d LINE                            < domain && 
    xargs -d '\n' -I LINE go run main.go -d LINE -o file2.txt          < domain && 
    mv *.txt /mnt/c/savehere                                                    &&
    dos2unix savehere/*.txt                                                     && 
    sort savehere/*.txt | uniq | tr -d '<>,' > results-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H_%p).txt && 
    python3 discord-notify.py
done
```

Comment: Thanks!!! You helped me on other asked questions, really appericate your help.

Comment: using your xargs code example, how would I set how many threads will be used? 
Do I understand correctly that by adding -P10 -n1  after -d will be running 10threads?

Comment: Read your xargs man page. Yes, the `-P` option is what you want. the `-I` option implies `-L 1` so you don't need `-n`.